# Pushing Date values from R to SQL Server table with missing values

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I'm using DBI to push a data frame from R into a SQL Server table. In the table, one of the columns is of type DATE. The problem I'm having is that, when any of the date values in the R data frame are missing (NA), I get an error.

Here's my code:

```
## Basic function to connect to the SQL Server database
con <- dbConnect()

## Create a table in the database
dbSendQuery(con, 
  'CREATE TABLE "my_table" (
     my_id VARCHAR(50),
     my_date DATE DEFAULT NULL
  );'
)

## Create some data
df <- data.frame(
  "my_id" = c(10001, 10002, 10003),
  "my_date" = c(Sys.Date(), NA, Sys.Date())
)

## Push the data to the database
dbWriteTable(con, name = "my_table", value = df, append = TRUE, row.names = F)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 22018: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
```

I know the problem is because of the one NA date value in `df`, but the reality of my data is that some records will have valid date values, while others will be missing. And since R does not allow NULL values in a data frame, I cannot set missing dates to NULL. Any thoughts on how I can get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create the table before writing into the database, the function `dbWriteTable()` will create the table. I think it could solve the issue.

```
## Basic function to connect to the SQL Server database
con <- dbConnect()

## Create some data
df <- data.frame(
  "my_id" = c(10001, 10002, 10003),
  "my_date" = c(Sys.Date(), NA, Sys.Date())
)

## Push the data to the database
dbWriteTable(con, name = "my_table", value = df, append = TRUE, row.names = F)
```

Comment: Yes I've tried this already, and it throws the same error. Putting in a blank string instead of an NA value does not solve the problem.

Comment: My post is edited, you shouldn't send a query to create the table before using `dbWriteTable()`